# How to validate built-in slot values in Amazon developer portal?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am using AMAZON.US_CITY slot type and using dialog management. Trying to validate slot values for the built-in slot so any idea how can it be done?

I have referred: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/validate-slot-values.html#configure
I know validation rule but for a built-in slot type, they are providing only two options 1. Accept only a set of values. 2. Reject only a set of values. So in the first case, It accepts values that match a fixed set of values you specify. In the second case, It rejects values that match a fixed set of values you specify. So what can be done for that case?

How can I create a validation rule for satisfying my condition?

Answer (score 1):

In your `Skill` you can add `validation` to `Slot` by :

Select slot from Intent

> Intent > yourslot > validations

**Beloe Image Help you:**

[image]

Comment: I know this validation rule but for a built in slot type, they are providing only two options 1. Accept only a set of values. 2. Reject only a set of values.  So in the first case, Accept values that match a fixed set of values you specify. In the second case, Reject values that match a fixed set of values you specify. So what can be done for that case? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The validation Alexa provides in the Alexa developer console is simpler as it's managed entirely on Alexa's side.

But you can actually manage everything also on your lambda function.
For example, if you are using the python `ask-sdk-core` library, you can catch the slot value, validate it with a custom rule you decide, then return an `ElicitSlotDirective` if it doesn't satisfy it.

Example code:

```
 if slot_value is not in ['accepted', 'values']:
      prompt = "The slot value is invalid, say something else"
      return handler_input.response_builder.ask(prompt).add_directive(
                ElicitSlotDirective(
                    slot_to_elicit=slot_name
                )).response
```

This will cause alexa to ask the user for another value for the slot, while keeping every other information about the intent, such as other slots, the actual intent, the sessionId...

[documentation here](https://alexa-skills-kit-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models/ask_sdk_model.dialog.html#ask_sdk_model.dialog.elicit_slot_directive.ElicitSlotDirective) and [an official alexa example on github](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-python-petmatch/blob/master/lambda/py/lambda_function.py)